# discord.go: get Permissions from a Member

Tags: go, discord

I am new to GoLang and want to make my own Discord bot. My problem is, that I don't know how I can check the member's permissions. Please don't respond with answers like "don't use GoLang for bots"... thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
p, err := s.UserChannelPermissions(m.Author.ID, m.ChannelID)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

if p&discordgo.PermissionManageMessages == discordgo.PermissionManageMessages {
    // when user has permission, this returns true
}
```

I fixed my problem with this code. Nice!